# Migrate down from Cedar to Bamboo?

Tags: heroku, cedar

Is it possible to downgrade an app from Cedar stack to Bamboo?

Hirefire doesn't work in Cedar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no ability to migrate from Bamboo to Cedar so it would be safe to assume there's no downgrade path.

However hirefireapp works in Cedar..is that an option? I'm using it with much success.

Comment: For me, hirefire simply isn't spinning workers up or down. As seen in: https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire/issues/26 I'd be much obliged if you could advise.  -- Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.1.1, DJ 2.1.4 (Stock), Hirefire 0.1.4

Comment: ah ok, I'm using the paid for service provided by hirefireapp.com - hirefire is the free version. Judging by the link the free version is behind in features to the paid version.

Comment: Lame. Thanks for the clarification, going to try workless instead. PS. How is hirefireapp.com?